# Bash | GREP list of hostname | While and For Loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, while-loop, grep

I am trying to fetch/grep few key values from properties file. I am able to fetch it using individual server - passing as full hostname.

**Working example**:

```
for i in hostname1; do
    echo $i
    ssh $i "egrep -w 'endpoint.address' /var/www/httpd/conf/server.properties"
done
```

**Output**:

```
endpoint.address=http://intserver-host/service/searchQuantity
```

If I want search for the list of hostname (hostname1 to hostname50) what should I use? I tried with while and for loop but that didn't work.

Using `while` and `for` loop, not working:

```
server="hostname"
count=1
servername="${server}$count"
echo "Server $servername"

echo "Entering into while loop"

while [  $count -lt 50 ]; do
    for i in servername; do
        echo $i
        ssh $i "egrep -w 'endpoint.address' /var/www/httpd/conf/server.properties"
    done
    let count=$((count+1))
done
```

Result:

```
Error: unknown servername  :|
```

Is there trick I'm not aware of? Your help/pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in servername
```

should be

```
for i in $servername
```

If you fix that you'll see that `$servername` isn't changing each iteration. It's not enough to set it once at the top of the script. You need to update it each time at the beginning of the loop.

```
while [ $count -lt 50 ]; do
    servername="${server}$count"
    echo "$servername"
    ssh "$servername" egrep -w 'endpoint.address' /var/www/httpd/conf/server.properties
    let count=$((count+1))
done
```

You might switch to a simpler `for` loop at this point.

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 50; i++)); do
    servername="$server$i"
    echo "$servername"
    ssh "$servername" egrep -w 'endpoint.address' /var/www/httpd/conf/server.properties
done
```

You could also loop over the server names directly if you wish.

```
for servername in "$server"{1..50}; do
    echo "$servername"
    ssh "$servername" egrep -w 'endpoint.address' /var/www/httpd/conf/server.properties
done
```